# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need your help on this. I am not sure why I am getting this error. Here is what I am trying to do. I am populating a `button` into the `GridView` based on the data from database however I have no issue with that. But the issue comes when I am trying to do `RowCommand`. I am trying to get the individual `id` from each `row` so that i can use for my `sql` query

```
Protected Sub GridView2_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowDataBound

    Dim row As GridViewRow = e.Row

    If row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim lb2 As New LinkButton
        lb2.ID = "lbCancel"
        lb2.Text = "Cancel"
        lb2.CommandName = "CancelRow"
        lb2.CommandArgument = "'<%#Eval('tripID')%>"

        row.Cells(10).Controls.Add(lb2)

        If row.Cells(8).Text = "Driver" Then

            Dim lb As New LinkButton()
            lb.ID = "lbEnd"
            lb.Text = "End"
            lb.CommandName = "EndRow"

            row.Cells(9).Controls.Add(lb)

        End If
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub GridView2_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowCommand

    If (e.CommandName = "CancelRow") Then
        Dim row As GridViewRow = e.CommandArgument

        Dim index As String = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "tripID"))
    ElseIf (e.CommandName = "EndRow") Then


    End If
    End Sub
```

I suspect the issue to be cause by `Dim index As String = Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(row.DataItem, "tripID"))` however i have no idea how to solve it.

Hope you guys can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you try to debug the code, you will get that you are getting

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow'

error at line

`Dim row As GridViewRow = e.CommandArgument`

Here you are trying to convert `String` into `WebControls` `GridViewRow`. In this case you should try

`Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(DirectCast(e.CommandSource, LinkButton).NamingContainer, GridViewRow)`

This will give you a `GridViewRow` and will evaluate value you are passing as `CommandArgument`.